# how to update entire server without changing server OS version

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, patch-management

I am new to linux . I have to patch a new build server. The server is with hundreds of vulnerability thats why I am told to patch system . This server is 7.9 version and registered with
satellite server . I am afraid If I will run   " Yum update -y " this will update OS version from 7.9 to 8 since OS version is strictly needs to be 7.9
I have updated kernel recently using " yum update kernel*"
My question is  how to update entire server without changing server OS version

Thanks in advance

Comment: 7.9 is least major version of rhle 7. So you can run yum update. You don't worry yum update will not upgrade to rhle 8.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot upgrade major versions of RHEL just with yum. It will always upgrade only on the same major version.

You must follow [a specific procedure](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/upgrading_from_rhel_7_to_rhel_8/index) to upgrade RHEL 7 to 8. Just running yum is not going to do it.

You can run `yum update` *without* `-y` to preview the changes which will be made before you accept them.

Comment: Thanks  Michael . I don't want update system from 7.9 to 8  I just want to patch whole server without changing the current version and current version is 7.9.   will " yum update -y"" work

Comment: @Newlinux-men Don't follow the directions to upgrade from 7 to 8.

Comment: Thanks again ,  I just want to patch whole server without changing the current version and current version is 7.9.   will " yum update -y"" work

Comment: @Newlinux-men Yes, of course. But read my post as well.